# Batch mysql query editor

Tags: php, mysql, editor

I have a set of MySQL queries in PHP files. I want to mass-edit these queries, e.g. add an extra `WHERE` or `UPDATE` clause to all of them.

Is there any existing software that can do this?

Comment: Search + replace in a text editor?

Comment: Hopefully next time you'll properly abstract your database queries, to make this a *lot* easier. Let this be a lesson to you.

Answer (score 0):

It's very unlikely that you'll find something that's capable of interpreting however you've chosen to implement your SQL query execution, in part because there's a plethora of approaches even using the out of the box PHP options.

As such, I very much suspect you'll need to search for whatever query execution function/method is in use and backtrack from there. (I suspect you'd need to do this anyway, as simply "adding a clause" would require human judgement/interpretation to achieve anyway.)

Hopefully your choose IDE will have a nice project/workspace-wide search that will make this a fairly trivial, if somewhat time-consuming, task.